# Generic non-existence of 1. Integral of continuous DS

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, differential-equations

Let $M$ be a compact manfiold and $F \in \mathcal{X}(M)$. We define a DS on $M$ by

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=F(\mathbf{x}(t))$$

In [1](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-098-01/S0002-9939-1986-0848891-7/S0002-9939-1986-0848891-7.pdf) it was shown by Hurley, that a generic diffeomorphism on $M$ does not have a first integral. But this is for discrete DS.

---

**My question is the following:** Is there a similar result for continuous time DS as defined above?

Or more formally, is it known that it is not $\mathcal{C}^1$ generic to have an invariant subset $U \subset M$ (non-trivial, i.e. $U$ itself has an open subset) such that on $U$ there exists a first integral.

(It is clear to me that by the straightening theorem for vector fields we alawys have an open set with a first integral but this set is not invariant.)